# Trying to Inject CSS Code

Tags: c#

I get a error saying

> for each statement cannot operate on variable of type 'mshtml.IHTMLElement' because 'mshtml.Element' does not contain a public definition of 'GetEnumerator'`

```
Var document = BookDocBrowser.Document as mshtml.Document

//BookDocBrowser is a WebBrowser control 
Var collection = document.getElementById("text");




Foreach (IHTMLElement input collection) 

//collection is underlined in red here when I start the //foreach loop
{   

    dynamic currentStyle = (input as IHTMLElement2);
    input.style.setAttribute(" wordwrap","break-word");
}
```

What I'm trying to do is inject CSS code into the HTML page that has been loaded on the WebBrowser Control

Comment: Please copy + paste the code, rather than hand writing it. Otherwise, you're bound to make a mistake which may mislead people. For example, most of this code won't compile. `Foreach` should  be `for each`, and so on. In any case, `getElementById` I would assume returns a single item, so you can't loop over it.

Comment: Sorry I don't have a internet connection with my PC.

Comment: That was the last edit

Comment: I see so how should I do this

Comment: rather than breaking into each element and injecting inline css .. how about injecting a CSS styles tag with custom style classes into your HTML?  For the above code it would be `#text{wordwrap:break-word;}`

Comment: Hey I didn't even come to that realisation yet thank you

Answer (score 0):

Because it looks like you typed your question out on a phone I'm going to try my best...

The exception you are getting here is because `collection` is not enumerable. The method `getElementById` returns elements by their Id and is unique. This means that only one will ever be returned.

---

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.getelementbyid(v=vs.110).aspx